# What is new in the December 2017 RFC 8259 specification of JSON?

Tags: json

The JSON interchange format established in ECMA 404 and  RFC 4627/RFC 7158/ RFC 7159.

But in December 2017, RFC 8259 and ECMA 404 version 2 were both released.

What changed in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

Most significant change is that UTF-8 encoding is a MUST for open systems.

More details see in [Tim Bray's blog post](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2017/12/14/RFC-8259-STD-90).